# What's the point of data-only docker containers?

Tags: docker

Instead of using a data-only container, I can ...

1. create a directory on the host (say /opt/shared_data)
2. Run every container with -v /opt/shared_data:/some/mount/point_inside/container

voila, now /opt/shared_data is effectively shared amongst all containers , correct?

If my understanding is correct, if I create a data-only container and then use "--volumes-from" when running other containers, I am stuck mounting them in the same location they were mounted, whereas, this way I get to choose which directory they are mounted as in my containers.

So why do I need "data-only" containers? Besides, the volume just points to somewhere on the host (/var/lib/docker/volumes?) which is functionally equivalent to my /opt/shared_data anyway right? Whats the advantage of the former?

Comment: Abstraction....

Comment: I'll add a 2nd.   No host permission issues.

Comment: What if /opt/shared_data doesn't exist on every host you're going to run the containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data containers have been largely deprecated in favor of named volumes. There's really no advantage to using a data container over a named volume, and includes the disadvantage of being stuck with the mount points.

To compare named volumes with host volumes (aka bind mounts), you have have a few differences:

- Host volumes include permission issues, users inside the container will differ from those outside the container and files may not be easily accessed from both environments
- Named volumes add the ability to use any volume driver so you can mount your data from remote locations.
- Named volumes are initialized to the contents of the image at that path, including all files and any directory permissions.

The latter point is a big one for me, it means you can create an initial default value for a data folder in your image, but update it using the container and keep those changes in a named volume. With bind mounts, if the directory is empty or doesn't exist, that's also what you get when you mount it in your container.